# Which aspect is actually communicated by Supine verb form in Estonian

Tags: grammar, verbs, finno-ugric

there is one bit of Estonian grammar that bugs me in particular for years already. Why to have 2 separate infinitive forms (so called, -ma and -da infinitives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_grammar#Verbs)

And I was told that, even though native speakers violate all kinds of rules when speaking/writing their language, they never actually violate this one: when to use -ma and when to use -da form.

But what aspect does it communicate? I am struggling to see how using "ma tahaksin ütlema" or "ma pean minna" would sound to a native speaker instead of the "right" constructs "ma tahaksin öelda" and "ma pean minema"

Was there any literature on this subject?

Comment: What makes you think the two infinitives encode different _aspects_ in particular? The Wikipedia article makes it relatively clear that the semantic difference is between the abstract concept of doing something vs a concrete instance of it. That doesn’t seem like an aspectual difference to me. Given its central in Balto-Fennic languages, this difference could perhaps be subsumed under the category of telicity, though it’s not obviously a telic vs atelic distinction.

Comment: I am not using "aspect" as a linguistic term as I am not a linguist  (sorry!).. but just as a synonym of "some quality, feature, .. aspect.. of a particular form choice". And I am struggling to see why in "to have to X", X would amount to something abstract/or concrete; while "to want to Y" , Y would be other way around.. How on Earth do they figure it out? I have seen that ancient forms of Russian also had this feature but dropped it; not sure what other languages still have it

Comment: this kind-a sheds some light but still not too much details on Estonian in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supine

Comment: In those specific cases, I think the form is licensed by the main verb, not selected due to its semantic nuance. English sort of has two infinitives too – infinitives and gerunds – and verbs can take complements in either, or both, forms depending on the verb. How do English speakers figure out that ‘I like/prefer/long to ski’ and ‘I like/prefer/enjoy skiing’ are all fine, but ‘*I enjoy to ski’ and ‘*I long skiing’ are ungrammatical? That’s just a part of each of those verbs’ innate properties.

Comment: tbh, I would certainly use at least "I long skiing" :) (am not a native speaker). Either way; this mistake is probably something even native speakers do; whereas in Estonian, I am being told that they never do this particular mistake; so there HAS to be more to it than just "certain verbs have this strange habit of preferring one infinitive over the other"

Comment: No, this is not a mistake native speakers make. “I enjoy to ski” is very obviously wrong, and no competent speaker would ever produce it, but they would at least understand what you meant if you said it. “I long skiing”, on the other hand, is so **completely wrong** that a native speaker would probably give you a strange look and not even know what you meant.

Comment: are there any sources for this claim? Is there any kind of authority to confirm that such usage is "very wrong" (and why)? Just curious ) I know that some verb/noun combinations sort of "feel weird" but.. that they're "very wrong"... that's a strong statement.. maybe it's in the textbook though, I have not really paid much attention to grammar when I learned English :)

Comment: Well, you can always look them up in a dictionary like Wiktionary – the entries for [_long_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/long#Verb_2) and [_enjoy_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enjoy) both have a _Usage notes_ section that specifies which form they are used with. The [appendix on English catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) says that “Most catenative verbs require that the verb following be in one or the other form only”, as here. I’m not sure where you’d look to find that _long doing_ is **more** wrong than _enjoy to do_, though.

Comment: If you look at the list of catenative verbs in the appendix, you’ll probably also find many examples of verbs that sound completely wrong with the ‘opposite’ form, even to a non-native speaker. Perhaps the most egregious case would be _have_ – if you said “I really have going now” (to mean ‘I really must go now’), I can assure you that no one would understand what you meant.